# Ckeditor onchange triggers for all the instances when only one of them is changed

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm using ckeditor inline to add some user-editable rows to a table using this code (the function is called once per row, the parameters are the Id for each type of editable column i want). Disregard the superfluous array building.

```
function activare_campuri_editabile_extinse(pu, adaos, cota, cant, cant_doc, pv) {      
var campuri_editabile = [ pu, adaos, cota, cant, cant_doc , pv];

$j.each(campuri_editabile, function(index) {
    var ce = this; 
    editor = CKEDITOR.inline( $j('#' + this).attr('id'), {          
        enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
        on: {
            blur: function( event ) {
                var data = event.editor.getData();
                if(ce.split('_')[0] == 'pu' || ce.split('_')[0] == 'pv') {
                    $j('#'+ce).text(formatare_cu_virgula(data));
                }
                if(ce.split('_')[0] == 'pu') {                      
                    verificare_modificare_pret('#' + ce, data, 'select_gestiune_primitoare' );
                }
            },
            focus: function ( event ) {
                var data = event.editor.getData();
                if(ce.split('_')[0] == 'pu' || ce.split('_')[0] == 'pv') {  
                    $j('#'+ce).text(deformatare_cu_virgula(data));
                }
            },      
            change: function( event ) {
                if(event.editor.checkDirty() == true) {                     
                    var data = event.editor.getData();
                    if(ce.split('_')[0] == 'pu' || ce.split('_')[0] == 'pv' || ce.split('_')[0] == 'cota') {
                        corelare_valori_tabel(ce,'adaos', 'extins', data);
                    }
                    if(ce.split('_')[0] == 'adaos') {
                        corelare_valori_tabel(ce,'pret_vanzare', 'extins', data);
                    }
                    if(ce.split('_')[0] == 'cant') {                                                    
                        corelare_valori_tabel(ce, 'cantitate', 'extins', data);
                    }
                    event.editor.resetDirty();
                }                   
            }          
        }
    } );
    editor.config.keystrokes = [[ 13, 'doNothing']];
    editor.resetDirty();
    });
}
```

The onchange function is meant to modify some cells in the row in order to maintain integrity of the data (using this example: sets the markup percent so that the sale price remains the same when the VAT or the entry price changes, among other things). The problem is that when one onchange event for one of the editor instances triggers, they all trigger. And seeing how two or more of the table cells are linked in both ways (changing the markup will change the selling price while changing the selling price will change the markup) the results are total chaos.

Did I do something wrong when using the checkDirty and resetDirty methods? or am I missing something? (running onchange plugin 1.7 on ckEditor 4.01)

I managed to work around this by adding onkeyup handlers for the elements that have ckeditor enabled directly. so instead of adding the onchange event trough CKEDITOR I added an onkeyup event directly to each of the elements in the array.

Comment: Is there an online example somewhere? When you say "triggers for all the instances" do you mean that if you add a `console.log("foo")` to the change function and you change the data of one instance, you get multiple "foo"s in your JS console?

Comment: yes, exactly that. Not only multiple, but all of them. All the ckeditor instances that have onchange handlers attached to them will fire when one of them is changed